# GetModuleFileNameEx Function returns wrong path of system processes

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

In my WPF project, I am receiving the path of the currently running process via the [**GetModuleFileNameEx**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683198%28VS.85%29.aspx) method. It works in most cases, but for example when the currently running process is "Windows Explorer" (a **system process**), I get "C$Å" (and other random characters).

Delphi developers had a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771682/not-getting-path-of-various-system-processes-by-getmodulefilenameex) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25063530/why-do-i-get-nonsense-from-getmodulefilenameex-on-64-bit-windows-8). The first problem was solved by setting a debug privilege. Unfortunately, It seems, this doesn't help me [in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541528(v=vs.85).aspx)...

This is the method:

```
[DllImport("psapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetModuleFileNameEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr hModule, StringBuilder lpFilename, int nSize);
```

Here I call the method:

```
// Get module file name
var buffer = new StringBuilder(4096);
GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, IntPtr.Zero, buffer, buffer.Capacity);
process = buffer.ToString();
```

Did anyone face similar problems or has an idea how to solve this issue? Thanks.

Btw, I am running a Windows 8.1, 64bit machine.

Comment: Have you looked at `System.Diagnostics.Process` (particularly `MainModule.FileName`)? Or is there a reason you don't use that class?

Comment: hi Dirk. Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Actually, I just found out that I can use the processId to get the name of the process (program) with `Process.GetProcessById(processId).ProcessName`. Didn't know that existed. Thanks for pointing me out to other opportunities ;) PS: If you add comment as an answer, I could accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class for that. Assuming you have the ID of a process you can use

```
var process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
var fileName = process.MainModule.FileName;
```

Comment: It is bad approach to use build-in methods just because they are "simpler"

Comment: @AlekDepler In what sense is this a bad approach if .NET is already a dependency?

Comment: In that sense that it very restricted functionality, for example you cannot get filename of 64bit process within 32bit process. And while developing commercial product you cannot change process bitness just to fix this issue - so this restricted, bitness-dependent solution which will work only in certain cases

Comment: @Eric It seems that Alek is a bit grumpy that the perfectly reasonable answers to this question don't solve his different problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking the return value of `GetModuleFileNameEx` for errors.

So, most likely you'll find that the function is failing. Check the return value, in this case a value of zero indicates failure. In case of failure use `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` to obtain the error code. Likely your process handle doesn't have the necessary access rights.

You would also do well to call the Unicode version of the function.

Finally, `Process.MainModule.FileName` is a much simpler way to get this information.

Comment: @AlekDepler This was an answer to the question, and I believe it is accurate. Perhaps you aren't familiar with how to check for errors on Win32. But this answer explains why the call to `GetModuleFileNameEx` appeared to return gibberish. How to deal with that and perform proper error checking. Remember that this is an answer to this question, not an attempt to solve your problem. Your problem is that your code runs in the 32 bit WOW64 emulator and you are asking for information about a 64 bit process. Quite different from this topic.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan forget it, I'm able to get x64 process info within x32 using WinApi. I just dont like people posting the most simple solution ever and defending their point no matter what restrictions it assumes

Comment: @AlekDepler I think you are confused between your problem and its solution, and the question asked here. The question asked here was why `GetModuleFileNameEx` failed. If you think it's an omission not to mention issues getting 64 module names from a 32 bit process, then you clearly don't understand how Stack Overflow works. We answer the questions that are asked.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I clearly understand how stack overflow works now - it's like a huge garbage collection which provides you mostly simpliest and because of that inefficient "solutions"

Comment: @Alek Depler - Entitled much? Sorry our answers aren't up to your high standards. Looking at your activity, I see that the few answers you've provided aren't well regarded, and your comments usually have the same bitchy tone as above. Did you know that a big part of being a good coder/developer/engineer is working well with others?

Comment: I was talking to you

Answer (score -1):

Are you calling the ANSI or Unicode version of GetModuleFileNameEx, e.g. `GetModuleFileNameExA` or `GetModuleFileNameExW`?

If you don't specify, I think you're calling the ANSI version by default. Since C# strings are Unicode, the garbage you're seeing may be the result of interpreting a buffer full of ANSI characters as a Unicode string.

For more information on this, see [Microsoft's page on the GetModuleFileNameEx function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198(v=vs.85).aspx).

Though you probably left it out of your snippet for the sake of brevity, and it wouldn't have helped you in this particular case, as [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan) pointed out, you *should* be checking the return value. :-)

Comment: It is calling the ANSI version but the marshaler knows that and converts the text to Unicode accordingly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - How does the Marshaler know? I don't see that in his interop prototype declaration.

Comment: The default CharSet on Windows is ANSI