# Getting the path of an executable file that is run by means of the Process Class through C#

Tags: c#, process

I checked in the internet for getting the path of an executable file that is run.
I found the answer:

```
string executingApplicationPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
```

which returns the path of the C# application I am running.
I was unable to find a way of returning the path of an executable file that I am running using the Process Class:

```
Process.Start("runningExecutableFile.exe", "arguments");
```

the C# executable file that runs the "runningExecutableFile.exe" is located in the directory of this file. I need exactly this directory. The problem is that this "runningExecutableFile.exe" may be situated in different directories and I just want to copy the .exe file of my C# application to this directory and find programmatically the path in which the file is located.
Please help.

Comment: `processObj.MainModule.FileName` is the executables path.

Comment: Have you reviewed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604475/getmodulefilenameex-function-returns-wrong-path-of-system-processes ?

Comment: you want runningExecutableFile.exe to sense its own path when it is called like you show, or you want the calling process, which is also a managed executable under your control, to find the absolute path of `runningExecutableFile.exe` from nothing than the current directory where the calling image is running from?

Comment: @Alex K Thank you very much. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you are looking for you could use the System.Diagnostics library as following:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace YourNameSpace
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Process[] pcs = Process.GetProcessesByName("YourProcessName");
            string path = pcs[0].MainModule.FileName;
        }
   }
}
```

.GetProcessesByName("..") will return an array of processes which will contain your desired process. To get the desired path you could just use the .MainModule.FileName properties.