# How to open a file with API CreateFile() and with the SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_NAME privilege enabled?

Tags: security, delphi, winapi

I need to use the API function `SetFileValidData`, but this works only with file handles opened with "the `SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_NAME` privilege enabled", and I don't know how to enable that. I searched but it seems too complicated for me. P.S. : I have administrator rights on my computer.

Comment: Use `AdjustTokenPrivileges` to add `SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_NAME` before you call `CreateFile` to create the handle. You'll need to be running with a used token that is allowed to add that privilege.

Comment: I don't know how, I never worked with tokens... It seems I need a token handle, and for this I need to open one with a process handle with PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION access permission and... I'm lost :(

Comment: There are lots of examples on the web of how to call `AdjustTokenPrivileges`. Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa446619.aspx

Comment: I successfully converted that procedure from C++ to Delphi and I understand how it works... but how I get that token handle ?

Comment: Sample code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6771988/886887

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarise the comments:

- You need your process token to have the `SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_NAME` privilege when you call `CreateFile` to open the file handle.
- You gain that privilege by calling `AdjustTokenPrivileges`.
- Some examples of how to do that can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa446619.aspx) and [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6771988/886887).